# Tomcat not responding after some time

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, amazon-ec2

I have a Spring Application with Hibernate as ORM and MYSQL as Database, Spring application is running on tomcat 8. Once we start the application, after some time tomcat stop responding.

I have checked the memory, its consuming 12% of 8 GB

I have got the thread dump, but i am not able to figure it out.

It seems hibernate is not able to take connection, but how to check and fix this issue.

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-6" #62 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb8882ba800 nid=0x136a in Object.wait() [0x00007fb839de8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    - locked <0x0000000080b35f60> (a com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:556)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.findById(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You are using c3p0 as connection manager. If you cannot get solution directly, Maybe you can try other such as DBCP?

Comment: Looks like you might have exhausted the connections in the pool.  Are you cleaning them up appropriately when you're done with them?  Does your back end hang onto them too long?  Run Visual VM and see what threads are doing.